# HTML5 Anchors not working

Tags: javascript, css, html, anchor

I am working in HTML5 and this is my code and i am following this tutorial-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDyJN7qQETA

The code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <body>
<article>Hello</article>
<meta name="description" content="Vaibhav chhabra"/>


<a name="pageTop">Top of page</a>

<a href="html5.html#pageBottom">Bottom of page</a>

<br><br><br>
<a href="youtube.com" title="Youtube Site website Titile" >Youtbe alone</a>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p>Hello Worlddddd22222222dddddd</p>
<a href="html5.html#pageTop">Top of Page</a>
<a id="pageBottom">Bottom of page</a><br>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

When i click on Page Bottom Hyperlink instead of taking me to the bottom of the page , it takes me to Page not found error ,same is the problem with Page Top.
Plz help

Comment: Where is your `body` tag?

Comment: You are not opening the `<body>` tag and you have a `</body>` in your `<head>` tag. Unsalvagable to me, every basic HTML tutorial gives you clues about that.

Comment: if you're trying to use anchors in a pagea, you don't need to specify the filename. `<a href="#pageTop">...</a>` would be all you need. and if your test file ISN'T named `html5.html`, then you're linking to an anchor in a DIFFERENT page.

Comment: If you're getting a page not found error, then the name of the page isn't `html5.html`.

Comment: Body tag added wasnt there coz of sum typing error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is some error in your code.
I have fixed it for you.
CODE-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Vaibhav vaihhbhav chhabra" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<article>Hello</article>
 <a name="pageTop">Top of page</a>
<a href="#pageBottom">Bottom of page</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="youtube.com" title="Youtube Site website Titile">Youtbe alone</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br>


 <p>Hello Worlddddd22222222dddddd</p>
 < a href="#pageTop">Top of Page</a>
 <a id="pageBottom">Bottom of page</a>
 <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you fix? Please explain your answer.

Comment: <a name="pageTop">Top of page</a>
<a href="#pageBottom">Bottom of page</a>           and these 2 lines See - < a href="#pageTop">Top of Page</a>
     <a id="pageBottom">Bottom of page</a>

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be working as expected, however your markup appears to be all over the place (e.g. misplaced or missing tags scattered throughout).

If you expect your link to be on the same page, consider just pointing to the anchor itself :

```
<a href='#pageBottom'>Bottom of Page</a>
```

Using the `href='#html5.html#pageBottom` approach will work as long as you actually have a page called that within an accessible directory from your current location.

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vaibhav vaihhbhav chhabra" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <article>Hello</article>
  <a name="pageTop">Top of page</a>
  <a href="#pageBottom">Bottom of page</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="youtube.com" title="Youtube Site website Titile">Youtbe alone</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Hello Worlddddd22222222dddddd</p>
  <a href="#pageTop">Top of Page</a>
  <a id="pageBottom">Bottom of page</a>
  <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did u create this animated image ?

Comment: I frequently use [Recordit](http://recordit.co/) to create simple gifs and then I upload them via Imgur. I think it can often add quite a bit to answers instead of forcing the reader to go explicitly check out the snippets.

Comment: Any image hosting provider should work. You would simply need to record your animation, download it as a gif, upload it your provider of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body> <!--Emphasis on the opening body tag and that is outside the <head></head> section -->

<h1></h1>
<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Creating an [Anchor Tag](http://www.boogiejack.com/html/html-anchor-tag.html).

> The name attribute allows an anchor tag to be used to point to a specific place on a web page.

```
<a name="top"></a>
<a href="#top">Top</a>
```